# To prove that if B is minimal spanning set implies B is maximal L.I

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried using contradiction. I write as

Let B be not maximal L.I set. So there exists some B'such that B is $\subset$ B' and it is L.I

Pick v $\in$ $B'-B$. Then v $\in spanB$. Then B $\cup $ {v} is L.D. So B' is L.D as any superset of L.D is L.D.
This is a contradiction

**Is this correct?**

L.I - Linearly independent
L.D - Linearly dependent

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's correct.

With much of early linear algebra, use contradiction, it is a mighty weapon and I think really helps you understand the fundamentals of Linear Algebra.

Also purely pedantically, the proof should be written as follows:

- Given V is a vector space and B is a set of vectors.
- Assume $B$ is a minimal spanning set.
- Assume $B$ is not a maximal linearly independent set (notation: L.I.)
- This means there exists a $B'$ which is L.I. and contains $B$. ($B \subsetneq B'$)
- Let $v \in B' \setminus B$. The existence is assured by the previous statement.
- B is spanning set, and so $\, v \in  \text{Span}(B)$
- Hence, $B \cup \{v\} $ is Linearly dependant (notation: L.D.)
- $B \subsetneq B \cup \{v\} \subset B'$
- $B'$ is L.D. as any superset of a L.D set is L.D.
- But $B'$ was assumed to be L.I. 
  ↯
- Therefore if $B$ is a minimal spanning set, it is also a maximal linearly independent set. QED∎

---

Just wanted to give an "answer" so it could be closed.

Comment: Thanks.This proof is quite similar to proof that IF B be a basis then B is minimal spanning set.. I got idea from that

Comment: you can actually use the same idea to show that (in finite dimensions) a basis is equivalent to a minimal spanning set is equivalent to a maximal linearly independent set... etc. (it has many equivalent statements)